# What's more famed: Elven or Dwarven armaments?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, the-silmarillion

Dwarven weapons and armour are famed for their exceptional quality. The skill of Dwarven smiths are unmatched, so they are in high demand across the land by all races (except maybe the Elves).

Meanwhile, magic is an intrinsic part of the nature of Elves. This is the reason given that weapons and armour produced by their smiths, though not physically as good as those of Dwarven make, are compensated for by the enchantments imbued within them. Such magical weapons are similarly favoured, especially when facing special foes such as the more elite servants of the Enemy.

In the LotR universe through the Ages, which of the two is more highly prized in the various great wars?

Answer (score 15):

If we consider the ***famous*** weapons and armour - by which I mean it has a name and a story.

### Dwarves

Perhaps the most well known dwarven smith was Telchar, his works included

- Angrist, the dagger that was used to remove a Silmaril from the crown of Morgoth - one of the most heroic deeds ever.
- Narsil the sword of Elendil, later reforged by the Elves as Andúril
- The Dragon Helm of Dor-lómin

Other dwarven works include

- the Mithril shirt of Bilbo/Frodo
- the black arrow used to kill Smaug

### Elvish

Named eleven swords include

- Glamdring and Orcrist, forged in Gondolin and later used by Gandalf and Thorin Oakenshield. They are recognised and feared many 1000 years after being recognised by the goblins in the Hobbit.
- Sting, a short sword of Gondolin wielded by the Hobbits Bilbo, Frodo and Samwise
- Ringil, the Sword of Fingolfin that he used in battle against Morgoth.

### Conclusion

From this small sample it would appear that the weapons of the Elves are very well known and feared, but they seem to be lacking on the armour front.

I would have to conclude it a draw, with Dwarves *winning* the armour category.

Comment: Are the *Elven Rings* weapons? -- Also, iirc, Celebrimbor taught the Dwarves of *Khazad-dûm* a thing or two during his days in *Hollin*.

Comment: @user23715 no they are not

Comment: If they are not weapons, what was their purpose? -- "Armaments" cover more things than melee weapons and armor and the three *Elven Rings* weren't made to be fashionable.

Comment: @user23715 This is not the place to discuss it. If you're so sure they're armaments feel free to add your own answer

Comment: Is the black arrow forged by dwarves in the _book_? I remember it being said in the movies, but I don't remember reading it in the novel.

Comment: @lfurini “Arrow!” said the bowman. “Black arrow! I have saved you to the last. You have never failed me and always I have recovered you. I had you from my father and he from of old. If ever you came from the forges of the true king under the Mountain, go now and speed well!”

Comment: @user23715 "But they were not made as weapons of war or conquest: that is not their power.  Those who made them did not desire strength or domination or hoarded wealth, but understanding, making, and healing, to preserve all things unstained."  That is Elrond's own words on the purpose of the Three rings.

Comment: @suchiuomizu -- While it cannot be disputed that they were made without **intent** for war, the fact remains they were used extensively in **defense** against the Enemy; to keep those things loved by the Elves "unstained" from the dominion of his will. Unintentional armaments but armaments nonetheless.

Comment: @user23715 put your own answer in stop spamming on mine if you disagree with it

Comment: What about Anglachel and Anguirel, forged of meteoric iron by Eol the Dark Elf who was taught by Telchar? (Was Angrist their mate, taken from Eol by Curufin? I thought it was a Valinorean dagger of elf-make.)

Comment: If Anglachel counts as both dwarf- and elf-make, it's probably the most important weapon in the series. Only it and Ringil (Fingolfin's elvish blade) are, or were prophesied, to be used against Morgoth.

Comment: @Ber it's not dwarf make. Being taught by a dwarf doesn't make it dwarvish

Comment: The dwarves also had armour and helms that would withstand dragon fire, as used in the Battle of Sudden Flame. They definitely bossed it on the armour front

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn the dragon helm is an example of that I think?

Comment: @Po-ta-toe I always thought they were different, the helms the dwarves wore and used to hold one back the dragons had lenses in that protected the eyes. I dont believe the dragon helm had lenses

Answer (score 10):

**The Dwarves**.

From the Silmarillion, chapter 10: *Of the Sindar*:

> Their smithcraft indeed the Sindar soon learned of them; yet **in the tempering of steel alone of all crafts the Dwarves were never outmatched even by the Noldor, and in the making of mail of linked rings, which was first contrived by the smiths of Belegost, their work had no rival**.

(My emphasis)

Comment: Yes, but what about *Mithril*?

Comment: @user23715 the dwarves controlled the source of mithril, so it would make sense that the elves didn't do much mithril smithing.

Comment: @y7vc -- Khazad-dûm was **a** source of *Mithril*. -- When I hear Telchar forged something as stunning as a single *Silmaril* I'll reconsider Dwarven handicraft. After all, one taste of a *Silmaril* slew Anfauglir - pretty potent weapon if you ask me :D

Comment: @user23715 khazad-dûm was the only source of mithril

Comment: @Po-ta-toe -- In the *Third Age*, yes. Not so before the fall of Númenor.

Comment: @user23715 evidence? Gandalf says in LOTR that the wealth of Moria came from Mithril as it was the ONLY source of Mithril. And it pre-dates numenor

Comment: @Po-ta-toe -- Consult *Unfinished Tales* my friend.